# Manipulating an array in C

Tags: c, arrays

```
int image[128][256][3];
main()
{
int a=0;
int b=0;
int c=0;
int d=0;
int x=0;
int y=0;

//code for opening and reading each file and saving it as an array for image1

while(a== 0) //while loops used so all files can be read and written at the same time
{ 
    FILE *pfile = NULL;
    pfile = fopen("image01.red", "r");
    for(y = 0;y<HEIGHT;y++) //reads the file from the top row down until the array is full to specified height
    {
        for(x = 0;x<WIDTH;x++) //reads the file from left to right until the array is full to specified width
        {
            fscanf(pfile,"%d", &image[y][x][0]); //reads formatted input as a stream. Red file assigned to positon 0 in the 3-D array as it must be the first file in the array or colour distortion happens on image
        }
    }
    fclose(pfile);  //closes the file after reading the file
    a = 1; 
    break; //stops the loop (breaks the loop)
}
while(b== 0) //while loop done again for the blue array
{       
    FILE *pfile = NULL;
    pfile = fopen("image01.blue", "r");
    for(y = 0;y<HEIGHT;y++)
    {
        for(x = 0;x<WIDTH;x++)
        {
            fscanf(pfile,"%d", &image[y][x][2]); //blue file assigned to position 2 in the 3-D array as it must be the last file in the array or colour distortion happens on image
        }
    }
    fclose(pfile);
    b = 1;
    break;
}
while(c== 0) //while loop done again for the green array
{
    FILE *pfile = NULL;
    pfile = fopen("image01.green", "r");
    for(y = 0;y<HEIGHT;y++)
    {
        for(x = 0;x<WIDTH;x++)
        {
            fscanf(pfile,"%d", &image[y][x][1]);//green file assigned to positon 1 in the 3-D array as it must be the second file in the array or colour distortion happens on image
        }
    }
    fclose(pfile);
    c = 1;
    break;
}
while(d== 0) //finally while loop done for writing the three colour arrays to make a single image array 3 deep
{       //code for opening and writing the images to save them as a .ppm file to open in Irfanview
    FILE *pfile = NULL;
    pfile = fopen("ppm1.ppm", "w"); //Opens a file and calls it .ppm
    fprintf(pfile,"P3\n"); //First line of new file reads P3
    fprintf(pfile,"%d %d \n", WIDTH, HEIGHT); //Second lines defines the size of the 3-D array
    fprintf(pfile,"255\n"); //Defines maximum component colour value
    for(y = 0;y<HEIGHT;y++)
    {
        for(x = 0;x< WIDTH;x++)
        {
            fprintf(pfile,"%d %d %d ", image[y][x][0], image[y][x][1], image[y][x][2]); //image files arrays are written together to produce the overlapped image of 3 deep
        }
    }
    fclose(pfile);
    d = 1;
    break;
}
}
```

The code above reads 3 .ppm files as .txt's and stores the integers in an array before writing the array into a new .ppm file for opening in an image viewer (here its Irfanview). The 3 .ppm's are the RGB components of an image and the code is designed to put them all together to produce the final image. Only problem is the Red component is inverted, so when the final image is produced the RED channel is upside down and flipped horizontally. How would I go about manipulating the array so that the RED values are rearranged to fix this error? Hope this makes sense. Thanks

Comment: It's worth pointing out that your while loops are completely useless in this code. Your code is equivalent to this: https://gist.github.com/sharth/64a42342f5e7966e20b8

Comment: Not more homework....

Comment: Part of the point of StackOverflow is to build a reusable knowledge base. If you don't want other people to learn from your question and its answers, you shouldn't put it up here in the first place. Edits that remove a question, and prevent others from learning from its answers, are very much poor form.

Comment: There is no code above.

Comment: The OP attempted to remove all the code. I Rolled it back to previous revision.

Comment: OP: Rather than deleting your code and referencing an external site, leave posted it here.  @wildplasser I rerolled it back to previous revision.

Answer (score 1):

So just read it "*upside down and flipped horizontally*":

```
fscanf(pfile,"%d", &image[HEIGHT - y - 1][WIDTH - x - 1][0]);
```

or store it that way:

```
fprintf(pfile,"%d %d %d ", 
  image[HEIGHT - y - 1][WIDTH - x - 1][0], 
  image[y][x][1], 
  image[y][x][2]
);
```